# How to properly list your papers that were "published" in a symposium proceedings?

Tags: publications, machine-learning

I was recently listed as an author on some papers that my PI submitted to the ASNE Technology, Systems, and Ships Symposium: [see here](https://www.navalengineers.org/Symposia/TSSCSS23). It says that the papers submitted to the event will be published as Symposia Proceedings which are now listed on their website [here](https://www.navalengineers.org/Publications/Symposia-Proceedings). Should these papers be listed as conference papers or do symposia proceedings papers have their own classification? Also, are symposia proceedings seen as lower quality than conference papers? These papers primarily cover the fields of machine learning and computer vision if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you asked your adviser?

Comment: "Also, are symposia proceedings seen as lower quality than conference papers?" This will quite certainly depend on the specific symposium and conference you compare.

Comment: I'm a relatively new R&D engineer in a government lab so I don't have an advisor unfortunately. I would ask my PI and or lab manager but a lot of our work doesn't get published in a traditional way so this is a little new for us. @ChristianHennig that makes sense. I wasn't sure if there was a hard hierarchy for publication quality venue.